# Failed AJAX & PHP communication on Localhost WAMP Configuration

Tags: php, ajax

First off I am new to AJAX, this is my first attempt at using AJAX with PHP.  The problem I have encountered is that although my XMLHttpRequest state successfully changes its state to 4, ie: complete, the responseText and all other response types are "" (empty).

I have tried really simple versions of my code and recently tried a copy of W3Schools AJAX & PHP example http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp which also failed to return anything.  This leads me to believe it may be a configuration problem but I dont know where to go from here?  Any suggestions anyone?

This is a section of my js which applies to the AJAX PHP Comms:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function() {
    alert("The button has been clicked")
    if(($("#title").val().length < 3 ) || ($("#description").val().length < 3 ))
    {
        alert("Title and Description must be 3 characters or more!");
    }
    else
    {
            var ajaxRequest;

            try{
                // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
                ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e){
                // Internet Explorer Browsers
                alert("THE PROBLEM WAS IE " + e);
                try{
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    alert("THE PROBLEM WAS second " + e);
                    try{
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e){
                        // Something went wrong
                        alert("Your browser broke!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }   

            // receive data sent from the server
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                    // Get the data from the server's response
                    var test = ajaxRequest.responseText; 
                    alert(test);
                    //console.log(xmlHttp);
                    console.log(ajaxRequest);
                }
            }

            //Variables
            var title =$("#title").val();
            var description =$("#description").val();
            var url = $("#url").val();

            ajaxRequest.open('GET','http://localhost/TestPHP/Model/AddNewVideo.php');
            try {
                ajaxRequest.send();
            }
            catch(e) {
                alert("THE PROBLEM WAS " + e);
            }   
    }
});
```

Here is my PHP code.  The PHP has not been tested on its own to ensure the SQL query works, but it doesnt even work if I just reduce it to echo 'hello world'.

```
    <?PHP
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//Connect to dBase
include("mysql_connect.php");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo 'POSTed Method';
  }
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    echo 'GET Method';
  }


//Debugging
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

//Gather Variables
echo $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["TITLE"]);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["DESCRIPTION"]);
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["URL"]);

//Insert new query
mysql_query('INSERT INTO video VALUES($title, $description, $url') or die(mysql_error());


//Close the DBase
mysql_close($connect);

echo $description;
?>
```

My Update and enhanced version of js using JQuery;

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(event) {
        alert("The button has been clicked")
        if(($("#title").val().length < 3 ) || ($("#description").val().length < 3 ))
    {
        alert("Title and Description must be 3 characters or more!");
    }
    else
    {
            // Variables to pass
            var $form = $("#AddVideoForm"),
            // Gather all fields 
            $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea"),
            // serialize the data in the form
            serializedData = $form.serialize();


            try
            {
                //JQuery Based AJAX HTTP Request
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost/TestPHP/Model/AddNewVideo.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: serializedData,
                    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    // Show success
                    alert("Wonderful It worked");
                    console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
                    },
                    // callback handler that will be called on error
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    // log the error to the console
                    console.log("The following error occured: "+ textStatus, errorThrown)
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                    // Display Completed message
                    alert("Totally Completed!  Hoorah!");
                    }
                });
            } 
            catch (e)
            {
                alert("THE PROBLEM WAS " + e);
            }
            event.preventDefault();
    }
});'
```

Comment: You appear to be using jQuery, is there a reason you aren't using jQuery's built in AJAX functions?

Comment: Hi excellent question thank you, I forgot to mention that I have also tried JQuery approach to no avail, still I get a completed state and response is again empty.  This approach was the first example I discovered which I could understand so I have tried to stick with it I guess.

Comment: Better use first jQuery AJAX functionality. Something like simple like injecting the response into an element. $('div#target_container').load('http://localhost/TestPHP/Model/AddNewVideo.php'); and just echo a string from there.

Comment: also, what is firebug showing for your xml request response?

Comment: Hi all.  I primarily use Chrome to debug but have also tried to use firebug but in all honesty I dont find it very intuitive and revert back to Chrome.  Im not even sure how to check or where to look for an xml request response in firebug?  is this anything close?  DONE
 4
 
HEADERS_RECEIVED
 2
 
LOADING
 3
 
OPENED
 1
 
UNSENT
 0

Comment: @elvispt Hi thanks.  I have tried exactly what you suggested and still get exactly the same response?  As in a completed state but response is still "".

Comment: Remove everything on the php and put an echo 'something';

Comment: better yet. I you access that link directly on the browser, do you see the echo?

Comment: Hi @elvispt.  Sorry, I must apologise. I made a mistake.  The PHP page does echo 'hello world' when I navigate to it.

Comment: in firebug. take a look at the console and look for the request. See the request data and check the response there.

Comment: Hi @elvispt. Sorry, I must apologise. I made a mistake. The PHP page does echo 'hello world' when I navigate to it. Typo :(

Comment: Hi @elvispt.  Thanks for your help.  OK Having found the request I receive the following (With PHP echoing 'hello world' only) Things have progressed slightly;  I receive this error the first time I run it: throw Components.Exception("prompt aborted by user", Cr.NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)    then the second time I run it I get back Hello World :)  Small win!

Comment: Try this:
$("#submitButton").click(function(event) {
/* ajax request here */
event.preventDefault();

Comment: @elvispt HaHa! Constant hello world responses without any odd error messages.  I am trying to understand what difference that would make and can only assume that because I am using an anchor tag (due to a number of previous posts suggesting that submit buttons and AJAX dont work well together) its trying to redirect and that method stops it from trying that.  Am I close?

Comment: I'm assuming it worked? Can i put the answer?

Comment: @elvispt Yes Absolutely it worked great.  I hadnt mentioned it before but this was part of a job interview due on Monday just gone.  Im not getting the job obviously, but its so nice to get it working with help :)  My thanks to everyone and especially elvispt A1 ++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few exchanges in the comments:
The answer:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(event) {
    /* ajax request here */
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The reason for this is due to the browser trying to execute it's normal behaviour when clicking an anchor or submit button (I don't know the element that was clicked). The preventDefault() is there to stop normal execution.

One thing to notice. Do use jQuery for the Ajax request. All that code logic above to do the ajax request is already done on the jQuery framework, and you can go from 20+ lines of code to just a couple.

Comment: For anyone who might want to know I have added my enhanced and far more robust version of my original js;